# Updating a control on another form with the results of a dialog box

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, jet, bindingsource

I made a windows form which contains a listbox (named `VenueList`). The listbox is pulling it's values from a list provided by a binding source `VenuesBindingSource` which is pulling in a ID for the value and a name for the text.

There is a button which is causing a DialogBox to appear which is asking for values to store in the database for a NEW venue. Once the values are filled and insert the database, what's supposed to happen is that the dialog box closes and goes back to the original form which invoked it.

However, instead of updating the list. The list stays the same. But if you close the form and reopen it, you see that a new value was added.

```
    TournamentSettings.VenuesTableAdapter.InsertVenueQuery(Trim(VenueNameTxt.Text), Trim(VenueAddress1Txt.Text), Trim(VenueAddress2Txt.Text), Trim(VenueCityTxt.Text), Trim(VenueProvinceTxt.Text), Trim(VenueZipTxt.Text), Trim(CountryBox.SelectedValue), Trim(VenuePhoneNo.Text), VenueType.SelectedText, VenueWebAddress)
    TournamentSettings.VenuesTableAdapter.Fill(TournamentSettings.VenueNameList.Venues)
```

- In the above code, `InsertVenueQuery` is the name of a query from the designer which is invoked to add the values onto the tableadapter `VenuesTableAdapter` which is used to fill the combo box on load. I also sent the `Fill` command to refill the table with the new value.

So the question is, should I go about doing this another way, rather than feeding the Table adapter and sending a fill command on to the datatable? Or is there something that I'm not doing here which I should to force that value into the list. I'm tempted to redo everything outside of the designer but that's a lot of code since I have to essentially run two commands (one to insert the data, and another to get the @@IDENTITY value since this is run on an access database.)

Comment: Is this Windows Forms, Web Forms, WPF, or what?

Comment: This is a Windows Form. (I think I already posted that in the question. )

Answer (score 0):

Okay. This one I had to think about for a moment.

Instead of me creating a block of done on the load event, I instead created a sub function called "FillVenueList".

I used the following block of code:

```
Public Sub FillVenueList()
    ' Adding values from database to a datatable.
    ' From there will add to the list box. 
    Dim VenueConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(DBconnection)
    VenueConnection.Open()
    Dim VenueConnectionQuery As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT VenueID, VenueName FROM Venues", VenueConnection)
    Dim VenueDataAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(VenueConnectionQuery)
    Dim VenueDataSet As New DataSet
    VenueDataAdapter.Fill(VenueDataSet, "Venues")

    TrnVenueLst.DataSource = VenueDataSet.Tables("Venues")
    TrnVenueLst.DisplayMember = "VenueName"
    TrnVenueLst.ValueMember = "VenueID"
    VenueConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

From there I called THIS sub on both the form AND the Add Venue window and I can safely see that this works. SO THAT is how you get a new value onto the form, don't use it as a part of the Load Event but rather call it from the load event block, then call it when you want to add to the list.